# Disable Button if checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below table structure generated from a rest call within it are input checkboxes, before the table is created there a static buttons that I want to disable unless any of the checkboxes are clicked

```
<div id="divbuttons">
  <button id="Reject" type="button">Reject</button>
  <button id="Approve" type="button">Approve</button>
</div>

<table id="GetItems" cellspacing="12">
  <tbody>
   <tr style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
    <td style="width: 349px;"><strong>Select</strong> 
       <input name="chk" type="checkbox" value="35">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 211px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 396px;"><strong>Requester: </strong>Test user</td>
    <td style="width: 149.2px;"><strong>Raised Date:</strong> 29/11/2017</td>
    <td style="width: 806.8px;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
    <td style="width: 349px;"><strong>Item Requested For:<br>:</strong>Desktops</td>
    <td style="width: 211px;"><strong>Bomb<br>&nbsp;</strong>ITSS</td>
    <td style="width: 396px;"><strong>Department:</strong><br>ITSS Infrastructure</td>
    <td style="width: 149.2px;"><strong>Job Title:</strong><br>Consultant</td>
    <td style="width: 376.8px;"><strong>Phone Number:</strong><br>032394</td>
    <td style="width: 213px;"><strong>Request Type</strong><br>:New Allocation</td>
    <td style="width: 217px;"><strong>Replacement Type:<br></strong>New Allocation</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('#GetItems tbody').html(`<tr style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
    <td style="width: 349px;"><strong>Select</strong> 
       <input name="chk" type="checkbox" value="35">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 211px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 396px;"><strong>Requester: </strong>Test user</td>
    <td style="width: 149.2px;"><strong>Raised Date:</strong> 29/11/2017</td>
    <td style="width: 806.8px;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
    <td style="width: 349px;"><strong>Item Requested For:<br>:</strong>Desktops</td>
    <td style="width: 211px;"><strong>Bomb<br>&nbsp;</strong>ITSS</td>
    <td style="width: 396px;"><strong>Department:</strong><br>ITSS Infrastructure</td>
    <td style="width: 149.2px;"><strong>Job Title:</strong><br>Consultant</td>
    <td style="width: 376.8px;"><strong>Phone Number:</strong><br>032394</td>
    <td style="width: 213px;"><strong>Request Type</strong><br>:New Allocation</td>
    <td style="width: 217px;"><strong>Replacement Type:<br></strong>New Allocation</td>
   </tr>`);
   
$('#GetItems').on('change', 'input[name=chk]', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#Reject').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#Approve').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#Reject').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#Approve').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divbuttons">
  <button id="Reject" type="button" disabled>Reject</button>
  <button id="Approve" type="button" disabled>Approve</button>
</div>

<table id="GetItems" cellspacing="12">
  <tbody>
   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've considered `table` & `tbody` is static & row are getting added dynamically.

Since the checkbox is generated dynamically, you need to delegate the change event.

Hope this solution will help you.

Comment: @user989865 Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tclynk/68bL2dw8/1/)

```
$("input[name='chk']").on("change",function(){
   if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#Reject').prop('disabled', true);
     $('#Approve').prop('disabled', true);
   } else {
    $('#Reject').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#Approve').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```